# jq plot is not displaying donut

Tags: jquery, jqplot

**I Have Following Code and includes**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="build/xcharts.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="build/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../JS/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/plugins/jqplot.donutRenderer.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" hrf="../dist/jquery.jqplot.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="build/xcharts.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<figure style = "width: 80%; height: 500px;" id = "myChart" class = "pizza"></figure>

<div  id="chart3" style="width: 400px; height: 500px; margin-top: 100px; position: relative;" class = "jqplot-target"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var s1 = [['a',6], ['b',8], ['c',14], ['d',20]];
  var s2 = [['a', 8], ['b', 12], ['c', 6], ['d', 9]];

  var plot3 = $.jqplot('chart3', [s1, s2], {
    seriesDefaults: {
      // make this a donut chart.
      renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
      rendererOptions:{
        // Donut's can be cut into slices like pies.
        sliceMargin: 3,
        // Pies and donuts can start at any arbitrary angle.
        startAngle: -90,
        showDataLabels: true,
        // By default, data labels show the percentage of the donut/pie.
        // You can show the data 'value' or data 'label' instead.
        dataLabels: 'value'
      }
    }
  });


</script>

</body>
```

**Problem Description :**

When I load my html page it shows an empty page. I have also tried to include jquery 1.7 on a fiddle I found on the internet but nothing shows. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to check the debug console to have more details about your error. To do that, press F12 button, and go to the console tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me its working chek http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/1xcn4bf5/1/

See debug console you and also check if you added thse after jquery js

```
jquery.jqplot.css 
jquery.jqplot.js 
jqplot.donutRenderer.js
```

Comment: It worked I had done what you are telling me before posting the question .. the problem was I had included jquery 1.11.1 the moment I removed that the donut appeared .. I dont know why but it did.. thanks anyway